# Firebase query function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to write a query function which returns an object. The problem is, in my case the function returns `undefined`.

```
var filterDataAccordingToDate = function (ref, startTime, endTime) {

    var filteredObj = {};

    ref.orderByChild('date').startAt(startTime).endAt(endTime)
    .once('value', function(snap) {
       filteredObj = snap.val();

       console.log(util.inspect(filterDataAccordingToDate(filteredObj, false, null));
      //Returns the correct object

       return filteredObj;
    });  
}

console.log("DATA RETURNED: " + util.inspect(filterDataAccordingToDate(travelRef, 1466439004, 1466439011), false, null));
// DATA RETURNED: undefined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Ami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6203078/ami-hollander) mentions, you can't return a result from an asynchronous call.

What you could do is process your results using a method and simply call your asynchronous call directly without expecting a return result:

```
var filterDataAccordingToDate = function (ref, startTime, endTime) {
  ref.orderByChild('date').startAt(startTime).endAt(endTime)
    .once('value', function(snap) {
      var filteredObj = snap.val();

      console.log(util.inspect(filterDataAccordingToDate(filteredObj, false, null));
      doSomethingWith(filteredObj);
  });  
}

function doSomethingWith(obj) {
  console.log("DATA RETURNED: " + util.inspect(obj, false, null));
}

filterDataAccordingToDate(travelRef, 1466439004, 1466439011);
```

I suppose it all depends on what you want to do with your data and how many times you wish to reference it.

**Note**: I do suggest placing your script in a self-contained function to avoid adding private functions (specific to a single piece of functionality) so that you don't pollute your global namespace. 
[Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) wrote a nice post about Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE) or you can make use of a [JavaScript namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript).

**Edit**: As [adolfosrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1736127/adolfosrs) suggests, you can also use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) but keep in mind what [browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) you wish to support.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with a Promise.

```
var filterDataAccordingToDate = function (ref, startTime, endTime) {
    var filterDataAccordingToDatePromise = new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
        ref.orderByChild('date').startAt(startTime).endAt(endTime).once('value', function(snap) {
            filteredObj = snap.val();
            resolve(filteredObj);
        });
    });
    return filterDataAccordingToDatePromise;
};

filterDataAccordingToDate(travelRef, 1466439004, 1466439011).then(function(result){
    //this callback will be trigger when firebase call finish.
    //result is what you set on the resolve.
    console.log("DATA RETURNED: " + util.inspect(result, false, null));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Firebase uses an asynchronous listeners to a database reference, hence you can't return from the callback.

You can store the return objects into your dictionary inside the callback.