# How to get value of a user's child from Firebase real-time database with exported function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get my users's phone number for example, with a function that I import from a database.js helper file to a class component where my main navigation is:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { AuthStack } from "./AuthStack";
import { TabNavigator } from "./TabNavigator";
import { ProfileAuthStack } from "./ProfileAuthStack";
import firebase from "../util/firebase";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";
import { getPhone } from "../util/database";

export default class AppNavigator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: "",
      isLoading: false,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    var name, email, phone;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        name = user.displayName;
        email = user.email;
        phone = getPhone(user.uid);

        console.log(name + " " + email + " " + JSON.stringify(phone));
        this.setState({ user });
      } else {
        console.log("not logged in");
        this.setState({ user: "" });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    } else {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          {this.state.user ? (
            this.state.isAdmin ? (
              <TabNavigator />
            ) : (
              <ProfileAuthStack />
            )
          ) : (
            <AuthStack />
          )}
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This is my function:

```js
import firebase from "./firebase";

//THIS IS THE FUNCTION \/
export const getPhone = function (uid) {
  var phone;
  var userRef = firebase.database().ref("users/" + uid);
  userRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {
    phone = snapshot.val().phone;
    return phone;
  });
};
```

now my `console.log` looks like this:

```
Nikola niko@gmail.com undefined
```

I can't understand why I'm getting back an undefined instead of the value itself
What Am I doing wrong?

my JSON tree in the database looks like this:

```
{
  "admins" : {
    "lessons" : ""
  },
  "users" : {
    "96GFQRlNQwQOu7zEEx7Gqp94NVq1" : {
      "admin" : false,
      "credit" : 0,
      "injuries" : "",
      "isProfileFilled" : true,
      "isValid" : false,
      "phone" : "123123123"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. Any code that needs the data needs to either be in the callback or get called from there.

Your code could be something like this:

```
export const getPhone = function (uid) {
  var userRef = firebase.database().ref("users/" + uid);
  return userRef.once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
    var phone = snapshot.val().phone;
    return phone;
  });
};
```

And then:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    name = user.displayName;
    email = user.email;
    getPhone(user.uid).then(function(phone) {
        console.log(name + " " + email + " " + JSON.stringify(phone));
        this.setState({ user });
    });
  } else {
    console.log("not logged in");
    this.setState({ user: "" });
  }
});
```

So the changes here are:

- The `getPhone` function uses `once()` instead of `on`, since it only needs to get the value from the database once.
- This means we can now use the `then()` returned by once, and we then bubble up the `return phone` by also returning `return userRef...` out of `getPhone`.
- Now your call to `getPhone` gets back a promise, which we handle with a `then()` block. In there is the only place we can safely use `phone`, so that's where we now log it and set the state.

This is an incredibly common problem, so I recommend reading some of these:

- MDN documentation on [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
- [How to return values from async functions using async-await from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function), which uses the `async` and `await` keywords that reduce the nesting.
- [Best way to retrieve Firebase data and return it, or an alternative way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905600/best-way-to-retrieve-firebase-data-and-return-it-or-an-alternative-way/34908497#34908497)
- [Firebase query function returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927555/firebase-query-function-returns-undefined/37928089#37928089)